Stuck on how to write this if statement with a method
I have been assigned this project that's due Friday and I have most of it done, except I'm stuck on this one part. I'm required to check if the previous puzzle has been completed correctly with an if statement, there are three puzzles and I'm stuck on checking if the second one is completed. I keep getting

Main.java:53: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to
int

line 53 is the if statement below by userInput.
if(i.puzzle2(name2,userInput)){
    Scanner puz3name = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("you have 3 chances to guess a number");
    int firstnum= puz3name.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i.puzzle2(name2,firstnum));

name2 is already defined above
public boolean puzzle1(String name, String userInput) {
    //examine the conditions for puzzle 1
    //if the user answers correctly the process continues
    System.out.println("checking...");
    if (name.substring(0,1).equals(userInput.substring(0,1))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean puzzle2(String name, int userInput) {
    //examine the conditions for puzzle 2
    //if the user answers correctly the process continues
    int lastdig = userInput%10;
    int sqrname = name.length()*name.length();
        if(sqrname%10==lastdig)
    return true;
    else return false;
}

public boolean puzzle3(String name, int userInput) {
    //examine the conditions for puzzle 3
    //if the user answers correctly the process continues
    if (userInput==(name.length()+ 10) / 3)
        return true;
    else if (userInput>(name.length()+ 10) / 3){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
        return false;
    }
    else if (userInput<(name.length()+ 10 )/ 3){
        System.out.println("your guess is too low");
        return false;
    } 
    return false;
}

These are the methods I'm using. I'm new to Java, so sorry if I'm leaving anything important out or I'm bad at explaining my problem.
Ive tried messing with the if statement and changing userInput to other things, but I have no clue on what to do.

When you are asking question, please ask the complete question. In this scenario please provide what is the puzzle.

you should have searched the site as explained in the [tour] (you should also have completed it)

It would be more helpful if you could post your entire code, rather than just a small snippet. That way, people can get a more accurate understanding of what is happening.
That being said...
It seems like your userInput variable is a String. You are trying to pass it as an argument when you call puzzle2, but the second parameter of your puzzle2 method expects an int. Java doesn't automatically know whether you want to convert a String to an int - you have to explicitly tell it so.
Since this is an assigned project, I won't give you the full answer - that would be cheating ;)
However, there are two key concepts you need to understand:

The type of the arguments you pass when calling a method must match the type of the parameters specified in the method's definition. puzzle2 is defined with two parameters, a String and an int, so you must pass a String as the first argument and an int as the second argument.
This post explains how to convert a String to an int.


i fixed it thank you for helping me learn instead of giving me the answer
